# How to delete the filesytem on a RAID device?

Tags: filesystems, software-raid

How do I delete the filesystem on a RAID device?

```
sudo blkid /dev/md1

/dev/md1: UUID="9a27b794-12d7-4794-9764-dda623f12e58" TYPE="ext4"
```

Comment: Add some more derails to your question.

Comment: How is this array managed? You tagged `fakeraid` which would mean it is a hardware assisted RAID.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a software RAID, i.e. created and managed via `mdadm`, then you have multiple options:

- An **immediate** solution, if you only need to get rid of the filesystem's *magic strings*. It does not actually *erase* the array's filesystem:

  ```
  sudo wipefs --all /dev/md1
  ```

  You may install this tool with:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install util-linux
  ```
- If you actually want to one-pass erase the array data, this may do:

  ```
  sudo bash -c 'pv < /dev/zero > /dev/md1'
  ```

  being the **fastest** method of actually *erasing* the array.

  You may install this tool with:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install pv
  ```
- Or more **secure** method, without the need of installing anything:

  ```
  sudo bash -c 'cat /dev/urandom > /dev/md1'
  ```

  Use `pv` if you want to watch the progress:

  ```
  sudo bash -c 'pv < /dev/urandom > /dev/md1'
  ```

If you would be more specific as in specifying what you actually want to achieve, it would be much easier to help.